# shortest single trip in the graph

Tags: python, shortest-path

I am new to Python and stuck on below problem. Was thinking of Solving with BFS, but no. Any pointers welcome

> Given a list of flights (in any order), construct the trip that this list represents. For example, if we have a flight from San Francisco to Los Angeles and a flight from New York City to San Francisco, the trip is "NYC to SFO to LAX".
> Assumptions:
>
> - A city will only be visited once per trip. (you can't go back to a given city after visiting it).
> - The list will only represent one single trip.
> - Input is not from a text file. We can consider any data structure for the input, no specifications.

```
# Flights:
# ORD -> DNV
# SFO -> NYC
# LAX -> SFO
# NYC -> ORD
# 
# Trip / Output:
# LAX -> SFO -> NYC -> ORD -> DNV
```

Appreciate the help

Comment: To me, it seems like the question is pretty deterministic once you pick the start point.  You just want to find the start point that uses all flights in the provided list.  What's your input to the program?  Is it a dict mapping origin to destination?  Or a list of tuples? Or....?

Comment: Input :Flights:
# ORD -> DNV
# SFO -> NYC
# LAX -> SFO
# NYC -> ORD

 Trip / Output:
# LAX -> SFO -> NYC -> ORD -> DNV

Comment: I am giving Input as cities with flight directions and output as shown above.

Comment: Is that input from a textfile?  Do you have to first parse that into a data structure or something?

Comment: Input is not from a text file. We can consider any data structure for the input, no specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that you start with the following input:

```
flights = {'ORD': 'DNV', 'SFO': 'NYC', 'LAX': 'SFO', 'NYC': 'ORD'}
```

In other words, we map each of the keys to a value (eg `'ORD'` maps to `'DNV'`).

The origin of the trip must be the key that isn't also used as a value (ie the start of a flight that isn't the end of some other flight).  We can find this with

```
origin = set(flights.keys()).difference(set(flights.values())).pop()
```

which creates a set of keys and a set of values and find the key that isn't in the set of values.

With this in mind, we need a way to build the list of stops.  We can do this recursively:

```
def get_flights(route, flights):
    if len(route) == 0:
        origin = set(flights.keys()).difference(set(flights.values())).pop()
        return get_flights([origin], flights)
    elif route[-1] in flights:
        return get_flights(route + [flights[route[-1]]], flights)
    else:
        return route
```

or as a loop

```
def get_flights_2(flights):
    origin = set(flights.keys()).difference(set(flights.values())).pop()
    route = [origin]

    while route[-1] in flights:
        route += [flights[route[-1]]]

    return route
```

From there, we just call that function:

```
" -> ".join(get_flights(flights))
```

or

```
" -> ".join(get_flights_2(flights))
```

Comment: @Pankaj, if you've got any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: This question does not belong here and you should be voting to close it instead.

Comment: @Coal_, I disagree.  Maybe the question was poorly asked (in which case, feel free to leave a comment for OP to suggest how to improve the question or edit it yourself), but it meats all the criteria outlined on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page.  Stack overflow exists to help people.  Have you seen articles [like this one](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d)?  They're right.  Lets be part of the solution, not the problem.  Being hostile to new users isn't good for the site.

Comment: A little late, but OP didn't include *any* attempt to solve the problem. This is simply not the place to ask questions about 'homework'. And yes, perhaps StackOverflow seems hostile to new users, but that's because it keeps getting spammed with off-topic questions.